# Euclidean space and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

I have some question that I get for homework.

Let $U$ and $W$ subspace of Euclidean space $E$. Then if $U$ is orthogonal on $W$, then $U^{\bot}$ is orthogonal on $W^{\bot}$.

For second question I know that if $U$ is orthogonal on $W$ than for every $x\in U$ and for every $y\in W$ $(x|y)=0$, but I do not know is this true, but I think like this, that because $U$ is orthogonal on $W$ than $dim U \geq dim W$(I never read this so I am not so sure is this true) but we have that $dim U+dim U^{\bot}=dimE$ and $dimW+dimW^{\bot}=dimE$ if use both than $dimU^{\bot}\le dimW^{\bot}$ so $W^{\bot}$ is orthogonal on $U^{\bot}$, so it is not true,but I do not sure.

Comment: Do you mean $U$ orthogonal to $W$? Assuming that the answer is yes, why do you say $\dim U \geq \dim W?$ Think of two perpendicular lines (through (0,0)) in the plane. They are perpendicular subspaces with the same dimension.

Comment: yes sorry my english is not so good :D

Comment: Note that in your definition of orthogonality, $U$ and $W$ play symetric roles. So there is no way it implies $dimU \ge dimW$ since $\ge$ is an antisymetric relation

Comment: I just think like that because we do not have so much on Euclidean space, and professor do not talk so much, so I want to learn here,but if you can help, I will appreciate that

Comment: @mfl I don't think so. Consider $\mathbb R^3$ and $U=Span(0,0,1), W=Span(0,1,0)$ we have $U \bot W$, yet $dimU+dimW=2 \ne dim(\mathbb R^3)$

Comment: You say "for the second question.."  what is the first question?

Comment: @F.Carette I agree. I have misread the question and I assume $W=U^{\perp}.$ Thank you for noticing it.

Comment: @F.Carette Indeed your example shows that $U\perp W$ but $U^{\perp}$ is not perpendicular to $W^{\perp}.$

Comment: @mfl I didn't even realise, but indeed, in my exemple $Span(1,0,0) \subset U^\bot  \cap W^\bot$

Comment: Does anyone know how to prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is wrong. $U \bot W$ doesn't necessarily implies that $U^\bot \bot W^\bot$.

You can find an exemple of a situation where it doesn't stand in the comments, in my discution with mfl.

But just to keep a more general idea, we'll keep a generic Euclidian space $E$.

Let's just assume that $DimE \ge 2$, you can check the cases $DimE = 0 $ and $ DimE=1$, independantly if you need them.

**Consider U={**$0_E$**}**, where $0_E$ is the null vector of $E$.

We have $DimU=0$ and therefore, $DimU^\bot=DimE-0=DimE$.

Since $U^\bot \subset E$ and $DimU^\bot=DimE$, we have $U^\bot=E$

Let's consider $W$ a non-trivial subspace of $E$ ($DimE \gt DimW \ge 1$).

By definition of the scalar product, $\forall x \in W, (0_E,x) = 0$

So $U \bot W$

Now $DimW^\bot=DimE-DimW\ge1$.

So $\exists x_{w^\bot} \in W^\bot, x_{w^\bot} \ne 0_E$

Since $W^\bot \subset E$, $x_{w^\bot}\in E = U^\bot$

So, let's put $x=y=x_{w^\bot}$:

$$\exists x \in W^\bot, y \in \ U^\bot, (x|y)= (x_{w^\bot}|x_{w^\bot})=||x_{w^\bot}||² > 0 $$